# Dual installed Ubuntu 13.10 with Windows 7 does not boot

Tags: boot, grub2

Dual installing Ubuntu 13.10 with Windows 7 was successful. I was asked to re-start and when I did it will not reboot. I received error message indication a "folder/drive" does not exist. Then a command prompt dialog "grub rescue>" opened. I have no idea what it is and what commands I should enter.

I tried to re-install Ububtu and it showed that I have both Windows 7 and Ubuntu installed and gave reinstall options. There was no option to delete/remove just Ubuntu.

I am stuck, and need help.

Answer (score 0):

today i tried to run both os's (windows 7 -that is already instaled, and ubuntu 13.10 - ina another partition), and guess what? as same as you, the message "grub rescue" show up. after many attempts, i gave up, i try many code lines, and nothing fix the problem. So in the end i restore the windows boot line. run the windows 7 disk in restore mode, open the prompt and enter this line (( bootsect /nt60 ALL /force /mbr )) after that you'll be able to run your windows normaly.

the way is to grab the grub 2 manual and look for solutions.